# Cypress | problems doing login test because of cross origin

Tags: google-chrome, url, dns, cypress

My company switched to B2C and now the login is performed with a redirection from another website. For this reason my login tests that used to work now are giving me a cross origin error.

Already tried adding chromeWebSecurity: false to cypress.json and it makes no difference.

Also tried to add this to index.js :

```
      on('before:browser:launch', (browser = {}, launchOptions) => {
        // `args` is an array of all the arguments that will
        // be passed to browsers when it launches
        console.log(launchOptions.args) // print all current args
    
        if (browser.family === 'chromium' && browser.name !== 'electron') {
          // auto open devtools
          launchOptions.args.push('--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs')
    
          // whatever you return here becomes the launchOptions
          return launchOptions
        }
    
        if (browser.family === 'firefox') {
          // auto open devtools
          launchOptions.args.push('-devtools')
    
          return launchOptions
        }
      })
```

Didnt make any difference either.

From what I read, many people are having this issue since 2018 and Cypress didnt seem to have solved it yet. Kind of make me nervous because I already have A LOT of tests written for cypress, so migrating would be harsh.

Do you guys know any workaround?

Here's the full error:

CypressError
Cypress detected a cross origin error happened on page load:

> Blocked a frame with origin "my company's address" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

Before the page load, you were bound to the origin policy:

> my company's address

A cross origin error happens when your application navigates to a new URL which does not match the origin policy above.

A new URL does not match the origin policy if the 'protocol', 'port' (if specified), and/or 'host' (unless of the same superdomain) are different.

Cypress does not allow you to navigate to a different origin URL within a single test.

You may need to restructure some of your test code to avoid this problem.

Alternatively you can also disable Chrome Web Security in Chromium-based browsers which will turn off this restriction by setting { chromeWebSecurity: false } in cypress.json.Learn more

Comment: I had the same issue in my project. After a research, I came to conclusion that there are two solutions. 1. Using Puppeteer/PlayWright to login, using UI, to obtain required tokens. 2. Expose required API endpoint that would allow to obtain tokens. I went with the second option.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit how to do this second option ?